# How to solve index was outside the bounds of the array "in my code"

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop, image-processing

I have an **array of pixels** extracted from a **bitmap image** like below:

```
Color[] Array_of_Pixels = new Color[n]
```

In this array, there are some of the specific pixels of my image.

What I'm trying to do is getting some **integer** numbers from the user and try to change **Red value** of `Array_of_Pixels[input_number]` with the **ASCII** Value that user enters right after entering the first integer. Green and Blue values will remain the same as before.

Note that I store the integer values entered by user and the ASCII values that has been entered right after each integer in two separate arrays which are named **Array_of_Inputs** and **Input_ASCII_Values** respectively.

While the length of Array_of_Pixels is **n** the length of the input values that user enters can vary from **1 to n**. (It cannot be bigger that n)

I have used a **for loop** like below to do what I described above:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Array_of_Inputs.Length; i++)
{
Array_of_Pixels[Array_of_Inputs[i]] = Color.FromArgb(Input_ASCII_Values[i], Array_of_Pixels[Array_of_Inputs[i]].G, Array_of_Pixels[Array_of_Inputs[i]].B);
}
```

But my issue is: although sometime it works perfectly, in some cases I get *index was outside the bounds of the array* error.

I've used **breakpoints** to see whether the size of `Array_of_Inputs.Length` or `Input_ASCII_Values.Length` get bigger that `Array_of_Pixels.Length` or not. And the answer is they don't.

This issue happens most of the times(not always) at bigger input length(near to the `Array_of_Pixels.Length`) but this is not repeated everytime.

Can anybody tell me what's wrong here?

Here is an examples of inputs that caused the error:

```
Array_of_Inputs = {0,5,10,15,20,25,3,8,13,18,23,1,6,11,16,21,26,4,9,14,19,24,2,7,12,17}

Input_ASCII_Values = {105,117,121,103,100,104,107,106,100,100,97,98,103,100,97,119,100,121,117,119,101,103,100,102,101,102}
```

Comment: Are you sure all the numbers that you enter are smaller or equal to `Array_of_Pixels.Length`?

Comment: @parisa Yes of course, I check it every time. I just didn't mention it to make the question shorter. :-)

Comment: int length = Input_ASCII_Values.Length < Input_ASCII_Values.Length ? Input_ASCII_Values.Length :  Input_ASCII_Values.Length; for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) { ....}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code broke with your supplied inputs at i = 16. At the 16th index in Array_of_Inputs, the value is 26. You're using this value to index the pixels and the pixel array only has 26 elements. The inputs can only be up to n-1. N is 26 for your example, so the max value is 25.

Comment: Sometimes mind stops, you help me when I was in this situation :-) Thanks